# How to access highest role based on role priority

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I have a synerio in that user mapped to two roles and roles have priority set like 1 and 2 ...my question is how to access highest code and role only ...

For exp

```
Code       Name          Role   RolePriority
1          Rehman        Abc    2
2          Rehman        Def    3
3          Neha          Des    1
```

So  i want Rehman with Def role and Neha with Des role

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` to select highest priority

```
DECLARE @test AS TABLE(Code INT,Name VARCHAR(100),Role VARCHAR(100),RolePriority int)

INSERT INTO @test VALUES(1,'Rehman','Abc',2),(2,'Rehman','Def',3),(3,'Neha','Des',1)

SELECT * FROM(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY RolePriority desc) AS 
rw FROM @test)res
WHERE rw = 1
```